# how to add a key in yaml file using sed

Tags: shell, sed, key, yaml

I have a scenario like this:

**manifest.yaml**

```
key1: "value1"
key2: "value2"
```

And I want to update this manifest.yaml file at run time to this

```
key1: "value1"
key2: "value2"
new_key: "new_value1"
```

so how can I add a new key at run time?

Comment: Something like this? `echo "new_key \"new_value1\"" >> manifest.yaml`

Comment: No, it is not updating the manifest.yml by adding new_key: "new_value1"

Answer (score 2):

Achieved the same by the following command:

sed -i '/key2: "value2"/a new_key: "new_value1"' manifest.yml

and in case if space(5) has to be added before inserting new_key: "new_value1" then it can be done in the following way :

sed -i '/key2: "value2"/a \ \ \ \ \ new_key: "new_value1"' manifest.yml